# Check if typescript class has setter/getter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript class which has the following properties:

```
export class apiAccount  {
    private _balance : apiMoney;
    get balance():apiMoney {
        return this._balance;
    }
    set balance(value : apiMoney) {
        this._balance = value;
    }

    private _currency : string;
    get currency():string {
        return this._currency;
    }
    set currency(value : string) {
        this._currency = value;
    }
    ...
```

I need to create a blank instance of this class:

```
let newObj = new apiAccount();
```

And then check if it has the setter for "currency", for example.
I thought that this is exactly what `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` does, however apparently I was wrong:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newObj, 'currency')
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newObj, '_currency')
```

These both return undefined. But chrome seems to do it! When I hover over the instance, it shows me the properties, and shows them as undefined. How can I get a list of those property names, or check if the property descriptor exists in the object?
[image]

Comment: `Object.keys(newObj)` ?

Comment: Keys doesn't work for undefined properties

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "problem" is that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` - as the name implies - only returns descriptors of an **object's own properties**. That is: only properties that are directly assigned to that object, **not** those that are from one of the objects in its prototype chain.

In your example, the `currency` property is defined on `apiAccount.prototype`, not on `newObj`. The following code snippet demonstrates this:

```
class apiAccount {
    private _currency : string;
    get currency():string {
        return this._currency;
    }
    set currency(value : string) {
        this._currency = value;
    }
}

let newObj = new apiAccount();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newObj, 'currency')); // undefined
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(apiAccount.prototype, 'currency')); // { get, set, ... }
```

If you want to find a property descriptor anywhere in an object's prototype chain, you'll need to loop with `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
function getPropertyDescriptor(obj: any, prop: string) : PropertyDescriptor {
    let desc;
    do {
        desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
    } while (!desc && (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
    return desc;
}

console.log(getPropertyDescriptor(newObj, 'currency')); // { get, set, ... }
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you performing a loop? I got the same result just using `return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(viewModel), key);`. I then test for the setter by using `return isNullOrUndefined(desc) || !isNullOrUndefined(desc.set);`

Comment: @MattSugden Sure, if you know that the property is defined on the first object in the prototype chain (i.e. the constructing class), then you don't need a loop. My snippet demonstrates how you could find a property *anywhere* in the prototype chain (i.e. the constructing class or the superclass or the supersuperclass or etc.).