# Do nothing if setter or property is not defined in Typescript Object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to check if there is no setter defined in Typescript Object?

I have following code:

```
class Sample {
  private _name;

  set name(value: string) {
    value = value.trim();
    if(value.length > 0)
      this._name = value;
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }
}
```

i set the values by a change listener in my html forms.

the problem is, if i have a form element what shows on a not defined object property it simply sets it.

```
sample = new Sample();
sample.name = "myName";
sample.myTest = true;
```

returns an object like this:

```
{
  name: "myName";
  myTest: true;
}
```

how can i prevent undefined properties will not be set?

using `sample.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)` allways returns false. `sample.hasOwnProperty('_' + propertyName)` also returns false.

`sample[propertyName] === undefined`  returns true on sample.name because there is not value set on initializing an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643254/check-if-typescript-class-has-setter-getter

Comment: @spender i have tested it but does not work in my case because i dont know the class type of the my Application.activeObject property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the instance `constructor.prototype` has the property:

```
let sample = new Sample();
console.log(sample.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("name")); // true

let object = {};
console.log(object.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("name")); // false
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Sample%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20_name%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20set%20name(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20value.trim()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(value.length%20%3E%200)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this._name%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20name()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this._name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20sample%20%3D%20new%20Sample()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(sample.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty(%22name%22))%3B%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20object%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(object.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty(%22name%22))%3B%20%2F%2F%20false))

Comment: Nice job gever.

Comment: thank, works perfectly. sometime you don't see the simple things